# Mongoose: increment the date field of a mongo collection by one month

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to update a date field of a mongo collection by day, week and month according to the requirement. I figured it out for day and week with the below code:

Set next day:

```
col.findOneAndUpdate(
{ _id : item._id }
, { $set : { nextRun : new Date(item.nextRun.getTime() + 86400000}}
```

Set same day for next week:

```
col.findOneAndUpdate(
{ _id : item._id }
, { $set : { nextRun : new Date(item.nextRun.getTime() + (86400000*7))}}
```

How to update for month in the similar fashion?

Note: I don't want to multiply with 30 as the updated field would be one day lesser if the current month has 31 days.

for e.g. if the field has value 2016-**05**-24T11:30:00.000Z , then the update should change it to 2016-**06**-24T11:30:00.000Z.

Tried with **getMonth()** but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the month as follows:

```
var nextRunDate = new Date(item.nextRun);
nextRunDate.setMonth(nextRunDate.getMonth() + 1);
col.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id : item._id }, 
    { $set : { nextRun : nextRunDate } }
);
```

---

A much better approach would be to use a date handling library like [moment](http://momentjs.com/), where you can use the **[`add()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)** method

```
var nextRunDate = moment(item.nextRun).add(1, 'months').toDate();
col.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id : item._id }, 
    { $set : { nextRun : nextRunDate } }
);
```

Comment: How do I increment the date by 1 day without changing the existing time? Please not that I want to update many documents and not just one.